# gulp-inject. Do not want to include build folder in output

Tags: gulp, gulp-inject

I have the following folder structure

```
_build
src
|- \images
|- \js
|- \sass
```

I have built a gulp process so that when finished my .build folder will contain my finished solution

i.e

```
_build\index.html
_build\images\*.*
_build\js\site.min.js
_build\css\site.css
```

I have got my gulp task to compile my sass files, and the generated file is being correctly saved into the _build\css folder

Now within my index.html file, I have the following within the head element

```
<!-- inject:css -->
<!-- endinject -->
```

Now what I am trying to get is get the following injected

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site.css">
```

but what I keep on ending up with in

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_build/css/site.css">
```

This is my gulp task to do the inject. p.s. I am using gulp-load-plugins aliased to $

```
gulp.task('inject', function() {
    return gulp
        .src('./src/index.html')
        .pipe($.inject(gulp.src('./build/css/site.css', {read: false}), {relative: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./_build/'));
});
```

Based on my interpretation of reading the documentation on https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject, using the relative option it should not include /_build/ in the output. However it is not being excluded.

How do I configure gulp-inject to properly excludethe /_build/ path

Answer (score 0):

You are telling inject to use the relative path to the file. But relative to what? Well, relative to the source of your injection.

If your source is:

```
./build/css/site.css
```

You are going up a directory in the tree so inject is standing at `./` where ever that may be. Meaning, `build/css/site.css` is the correct relative path.

Now if your source on the other hand is:

```
build/css/site.css
```

The relative path to the css is `/css/site.css`.

Long story short. Call inject from the correct directory:

```
gulp.task('inject', function() {
    return gulp

        .src('./src/index.html')
        .pipe($.inject(gulp.src('build/css/site.css', {read: false}), {relative: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./_build/'));
});
```

Eliminate the `./`

**Edit**

You may need to change and play with your cwd (current working directory)